# Support to 64-bit gives error on adding ndk.abiFilters in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Most of the android developers must have got the message from Google to update the apps to support 64-bit architecture by Aug 2019. The detailed instructions are given here:
[Ensure that your app supports 64-bit devices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

In my app, I found that the 32-bit libs are used and therefore I have to update the app to support 64-bit architecture. As suggested in the guide above, I added the following in `build.gradle` file:

```
ndk.abiFilters = 'armeabi-v7a' 'arm64-v8a' 'x86' 'x86_64'
```

However, after that, I get following error in building the app:

> Error:(35, 0) Could not find method armeabi-v7a() for arguments
>   [arm64-v8a] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null,
>   minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'},
>   targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'},
>   renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=3, versionName=1.2,
>   applicationId=, testApplicationId=null,
>   testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={},
>   testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null,
>   resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={},
>   mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
>   mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

Has anybody already tried updating the app to 64-bit? Any idea, how to fix this issue?

Comment: I think it should be `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`. Not sure why they used an equals sign and spaces instead of commas on the developer page.

Comment: @Michael you are right. It worked. Incorrect documentation by Google!

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Just sent a commit to fix the docs, so that should at least be fixed soon. Don't hesitate to file bugs when you find mistakes like this. They're easy to fix as long as we know about them.

Comment: They have fixed the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done by updating the build gradle defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.test.64bitapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 42
    versionName "1.0.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64'
}
```

or

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.swypmedia"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0.2"
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64'
    }
}
```

I have tested this on android-native and react-native app. 
build was successful and app was working.

Comment: I am having the same issue. And I tried option 1. But the option 1 i.e ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64' not working. I have just checked.

Answer (score 2):

For latest kotlin dsl

```
ndk {
     abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
     abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [NdkOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html), `abiFilters` is defined as `Set<String>`

```
Set<String> abiFilters
```

In groovy, `Set` is initialised using below syntax (if you want to use the operator '`=`'):

```
Set<String> mySet = ["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"]
```