# Android APK Contains libs folder containing extra data (PFA)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface, apk

While analyzing my APK, I saw a huge part of my APK is occupied by the libs folder itself(~42MB), I am using two below Libraries with other Android Native and Firebase Libraries (it has no effects on lib folder):

implementation 'com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

Please help me with a solution to remove this lib folder or reduce its size.

[image]

Comment: Check the github [doc](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#why-resulting-apk-is-so-big) "why-resulting-apk-is-so-big" for android-pdf-viewer which explains that it must handle many architectures.  And it offers a solution.

Comment: The "mips" platform is dead, you can safely remove these libraries. And the x86 platform too, when it comes to physical devices. It is only required if you want that the app can be installed in an emulator. Set an appropriate filter for the platform: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54476308/150978

Comment: Took reference from both the comments above, and I was able to reduce the size a bit, also understood a few things..Thank a lot :)